# Deleting records from the created form in c#

Tags: c#

I m working with c#, in this i want to delete record from the form for that i have the following code..

```
     private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  Source=C:\\Documents and Settings\\mayur patil\\My Documents\\Dairy_db\\tblCompany.mdb";
        con.Open();
        string sql = "DELETE FROM tblCompany WHERE (CoCode = 1)";

    }
```

but i m not getting the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup an OleDbCommand

The full code for your case,

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  Source=C:\\Documents and Settings\\mayur patil\\My Documents\\Dairy_db\\tblCompany.mdb";
        string sql = "DELETE FROM tblCompany WHERE (CoCode = 1)";

        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
```

For more information of the whole implementation, read here
http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/DeletedatabaserecordsthroughOleDbCommandandverifytheresults.htm

Comment: on "con.Open();" it is giving "Could not find installable ISAM."

Comment: Can you start another thread on that as I think it's a separate issue from the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute an [`OleCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.aspx) with your SQL and connection.